# Multiple Modals One Script

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I will have some where around 40 different Modals on the same page, and rather than having a scrip line for each, I am trying to create a way to use one script to run the whole thing. Started with code that worked to display one at a time, but I tried to re work it so that any time the link is clicked it updates the code and the correct Modal is displayed.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkk4twn8/)

I found others on here, but didn't seem to answer why mine wasn't working. I am new to JavaScript, so any help is appreciated.

```
  var modal = "",
  lnk = "",
  lnkNumb = "",
  modalID = "",
  lnkID = "",
  span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

$('[class^="lnk"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  lnkNumb = this.className.replace('lnk', '');
  lnkID = ('lnk' + lnkNumb);
  lnk = document.getElementById(lnkID);
  modalID = ('modal' + lnkNumb);
  modal = document.getElementById(modalID);
});

// When the user clicks the Link, open the modal 
lnk.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

The content I will be displaying in the Modal will have at least one header, and anywhere from 1 to 6 paragraphs below that. I need to be able to style and format each of them using styles and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a single modal element then populate it's content dynamically based on a JSON object like this (CSS can stay the same).  When a link is clicked, the '.modal-btn' click listener gets that link's data-modal-id attribute, then uses that attribute to access the 'modalData' JSON object and it's relative data:

HTML:

```
<a id="btnB12" class="modal-btn" data-modal-id="B12" href="#">B12</a>
<a id="btnB02" class="modal-btn" data-modal-id="B02" href="#">B02</a>


<!-- single modal -->
<div class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <h2 class="modal-header"></h2>
    <p class="modal-body"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var modalData = {
  "B12": {
    "header":"Modal B12",
    "body":"Here's the text for Modal B12"
  },
  "B02": {
    "header":"Modal B02",
    "body":"Here's the text for Modal B02"
  }
}

//open modal
$('.modal-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var modalId = $(e.currentTarget).data('modal-id');
  $('.modal-header').text(modalData[modalId].header);
  $('.modal-body').text(modalData[modalId].body);
  $('.modal').show();
});

//close modal
$('.close').on('click', function(e){
    $('.modal').hide();
});
```

The JSON object could also be obtained via an AJAX call instead, if you wanted a modal that might be based off an external API's JSON data.

Comment: Will the Code accept HTML code as I will be putting in headers with this? Pulling something external isn't an option with the current site firewall.

Comment: Yeah, it'll work fine with headers, just make sure you put the jQuery link in the <head> tag before inserting these scripts as my Javascript relies on it (which I assumed was ok, based on it being present in your Fiddle).

Comment: That wouldn't work, as it will go from a  Heading to a paragraph: Example:

`<h3>B12</h3>
 <p>Sequi nam consectetur veritatis cumque tenetur architecto quasi obcaecati! Aliquam totam praesentium aspernatur modi accusantium minus sequi harum rem aperiam!Sequi nam consectetur veritatis cumque tenetur architecto quasi obcaecati! Aliquam totam praesentium aspernatur modi accusantium minus sequi harum rem aperiam!</p>`

Comment: I just put the heading in the modal as an example to show you how to access and populate the elements inside the modal.  What exactly are you trying to do?  You'd probably have to tweak my Javascript to access the right elements, i'm mainly setting you up a template to reference and see how it works.  What do you HAVE to have inside the modal?  A single header and a paragraph?  That's what my JSON does.  Based on the link you click, it finds that JSON object and then the 'header' and 'body' keys to get those values.

Comment: Btw, @UltimateNoob, the 'header' and 'body' nodes in the JSON are probably misleading.  Those refer to the header and body elements of the modal itself... they're simply meant to populate those text values in the modal.  These aren't the same as the actual HTML page headers, i.e. `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`.  My Javascript and HTML is supposed to completely replace your current Javascript and HTML, in case that's part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry if I am not making sense as I am not Familiar with JSON. This would work great if they were all just 1 header and then 1 paragraph. The content I am working with will have anywhere from 1 to 6 paragraphs. I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: I would highly recommend spending a little time learning about JSON and how it works.  It has pretty much become the standard data-transfer and parsable format in Javascript and nearly all APIs nowadays.  It's similar to XML or HTML, in that it's nested content, that data is just accessed using an Object Oriented style.  Very powerful.  Just follow through these W3 tutorials and you'll be set (probably take you like 20 minutes).  It's really very simple once you understand how it works but consider it essential knowledge for all Javascript devs.  [JSON Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)

Comment: @UltimateNoob  Not sure if you gave up on this or moved on but I made my own Codepen to help clarify things a little more.  It allows you to add as many or little paragraphs as you want to your modal.  I put a lot of comments in to better explain what is going on.  Feel free to let me know if you need further help.  [Dynamic Modal](http://codepen.io/midgitsuu/pen/NxErLv)

Comment: It took some working, but your last example gave me the pieces I needed. Thanks a ton. Still trying to figure this all out and how it works.